# Filtering spikes from range data

Tags: ros, range

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Is it possible to use the [filters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/filters) package to remove spikes from real-time range data returned from sonar or IR sensors?  I have a small robot running ROS that uses a number of sonar and IR sensors to detect obstacles.  Every once in awhile the sensors will return a spurious value that can cause the robot to think there is an obstacle when there isn't.  I don't want to use a mean filter because this slows down the robot's response to an obstacle that really is there.  I just want to remove the spikes.

I can easily code this myself but I was wondering if the existing ROS filters can be used for the task?

Thanks!

patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48262/filtering-spikes-from-range-data/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2012-11-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-11-16**:
Thanks @Peshala--I will give that a try assuming it will work over a temporal series rather than a spatial laserscan.  (Or maybe that's the way it works with the laserscan as well.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can have a look at http://ros.org/wiki/laser_filters in addition to filters package; especially the ScanShadowsFilter

---

Originally posted by [ChickenSoup](https://answers.ros.org/users/791/chickensoup/) with karma: 387 on 2012-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0